# HasMany relationship attach model without saving directly

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

The following is just an example: Take the following two models with their relationships:

```
User => hasMany('Address', 'user_id')
Address => => belongsTo('User', 'user_id')
```

I want to be able to link an address with an user with out directly saving it.
something like:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = "John";

$address1 = new Address();
$address1->street = "Foo street";

$address2 = new Address();
$address2->street = "Bar street";

$user->addresses()->push($address1);
$user->addresses()->push($address2);

//do some stuff to maybe validate some things or pass the user object to some other controllers that handels it

//Save the user and the addresses here.
$user->save()
```

So this different that $user->addresses()->saveMany([$address1, $address2]);
Hope you anyone give me an elegant solution.

Comment: why do a `$address1 = new Address();` if you don't plan on saving it? Or is Foo street an existing record inside the db?

Comment: I want pass to user object to a validator class that validates everything before saving it.

Answer (score -1):

You should distinguish your validation action from the save action. You can achieve this by creating different methods in the Object Controller. One for the validations that you will check for duplicates,similar etc and then if validation passes you should redirect to a store route where you 'll create and save the objects.